# Text box is not getting enabled on clearing a dependent text box using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are two text boxes in my page.

Name text box

```
<input type="text" onblur="matchUserName(true)" onkeyup="clearOther('txtUserName','txtUserID')" onkeydown="Search_OnKeyDown(event,this)" style="width: 250px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName">
```

UserID text box

```
<input type="text" onblur="matchUserID(true)" onkeyup="clearOther('txtUserID','txtUserName')" onkeydown="Search_OnKeyDown(event,this)" style="width: 250px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" id="txtUserID" name="txtUserID">
```

My scenario is input something in **userID text box**. **Name text box** will be changed to read only. Then clear the **userID text box**.

Expected behavior: **Name text box** should be available for inputting. Status should be changed back to normal from read only.

Actual behavior:
**Name text box** is not getting enabled for inputting. Still the status is read only.

`element.clear()` is used to clear the **userID text field**.

Comment: can you show us the demo? maybe jsfiddle

Comment: did uyou mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/kggz4cog/

Comment: i think page refresh will also do the trick

Comment: I cant do refresh here. Its a popup.

Answer (score 1):

Some times for inter-dependency the focus needs to be shifted. Try:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

after clearing.

Comment: Sure.It helped.Done :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried clicking some where on the page after clearing the userID text? Click somewhere on clearing, then mostly it will enabled.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: I tried clicking on some of the elements inside the page. It dint work out.